# How can I redirect correctly with age verification script?

Tags: php, javascript

After a lot of searching along with trial and errors, I stumped.
What is wrong with the code that the redirect does not allow me to access the actual site? I'm not able to get the age input to direct me to the main site, or index.php. Whatever date is input redirects to where a user would go if the answer is wrong - in this case, youtube.

Here's what I have in index.php working locally:

```
<?php

@session_start();
$url = 'http://localhost/J2.5/index.php';

if (!isset($_COOKIE['Visited'])) {
    $_COOKIE['Visited'] = 1;
    $url = 'http://localhost/J2.5/ageverificationone.php';
}

header("Location: {$url}");

?>
```

That part works great to pop up the actual page where the age verification script is located - ageverificationone.php (can be any name..tried a lot of variations):

```
<?php
session_start(); 

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST') 
{ 
if(isset($_POST['YES'])) 
{ 
$redirect=isset($_GET['return'])?urldecode($_GET['return']):'./'; 
$expire=isset($_GET['x']) && is_numeric($_GET['x'])?intval($_GET['x']):-1; 
if($expire==-1) 
{ 
$_SESSION['verified']="yes"; 
header("location: ".$redirect); 
exit(0); 
} 
if($expire==0) 
{ 
setcookie("verified", "yes",mktime(0,0,0,01,01,date("Y")+30)); 
$_SESSION['verified']="yes"; 
header("location: ".$redirect); 
exit(0); 
} 
setcookie("verified", "yes",(time()+$expire)); 
$_SESSION['verified']="yes"; 
header("location: http://www.superiorvaping.com/"); 
exit(0); 
}else{ 
header("location: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gppbrYIcR80"); 
exit(0); 
} 
} 

?>
<html>
<head>
<title>Age Verification</title>
<script language=Javascript>
  <!--
  function isNumberKey(evt)
  {
     var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
     if (charCode != 46 && charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
        return false;

     return true;
  }
  //-->
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function jumpField(elmnt,content)
{
if (content.length==elmnt.maxLength)
{
next=elmnt.tabIndex
if (next<document.forms[0].elements.length)
    {
    document.forms[0].elements[next].focus()
    }
}
}
</script>
<script src="http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.5/full/jquery.tools.min.js"></script> 
<script src="js/fade.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="js/ageverify.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body id="body" OnLoad="document.ageVerifyForm.month.focus();">
<img src="images/logoVerify.png" alt="Superior Vaping" id="logoVerify" /><br />
<p id="welcome">Welcome! Please enter your date of birth.</p>
<form id="ageVerifyForm" name="ageVerifyForm" action="" method="POST" onsubmit="return     formCheck(this);">
<input type="text" tabindex="1" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" onkeyup="jumpField(this,this.value)" id="month" name="month" maxlength="2" size="2" required="required" value="MM" onfocus="value=''" />
<input type="text" tabindex="2" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" onkeyup="jumpField(this,this.value)" id="day" name="day" maxlength="2" size="2" required="required" value="DD" onfocus="value=''"  />
<input type="text" tabindex="3" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" onkeyup="jumpField(this,this.value)" id="year" name="year" maxlength="4" size="4" required="required" value="YYYY" onfocus="value=''" />
<br />
<input type="submit" value="Enter Superior Vaping" id="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
<script language="JavaScript">
<!--
function formCheck(formobj){
// Enter name of mandatory fields
var fieldRequired = Array("month", "day", "year");
// Enter field description to appear in the dialog box
var fieldDescription = Array("month", "day", "year");
// dialog message
var alertMsg = "Please complete the following fields:\n";

var l_Msg = alertMsg.length;

for (var i = 0; i < fieldRequired.length; i++){
    var obj = formobj.elements[fieldRequired[i]];
    if (obj){
        switch(obj.type){
        case "select-one":
            if (obj.selectedIndex == -1 || obj.options[obj.selectedIndex].text == ""){
                alertMsg += " - " + fieldDescription[i] + "\n";
            }
            break;
        case "select-multiple":
            if (obj.selectedIndex == -1){
                alertMsg += " - " + fieldDescription[i] + "\n";
            }
            break;
        case "text":
        case "textarea":
            if (obj.value == "" || obj.value == null){
                alertMsg += " - " + fieldDescription[i] + "\n";
            }
            break;
        default:
        }
        if (obj.type == undefined){
            var blnchecked = false;
            for (var j = 0; j < obj.length; j++){
                if (obj[j].checked){
                    blnchecked = true;
                }
            }

        }
    }
}

if (alertMsg.length == l_Msg){
    return true;
}else{
    document.getElementById("error").innerHTML="All Fields Must be Filled out";
    return false;
}
}
// -->
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I'm using this in a Joomla foundation. This is several scripts slapped together to at least work as much as it does.
As mentioned, the final step is missing - getting correct redirect working with a cookie so the user only gets the age verification once, and it will come up no matter the page of entry.
This is for a vaping site and they mandate age verification.

I'm doing this locally using WAMP as the development grounds.

Thanks
Thomas

Comment: Welcome to SO :) I'd suggest you modify your question a bit so you'd get more of a response. You could make it easier to read (your PHP code could do with some indentation). You could - and probably should - reduce it to the minimum required to reproduce the problem. I got the impression that many around here will answer focused questions, as opposed to debugging somebody else's code. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

try changing your php code from:

```
if (!isset($_COOKIE['Visited'])) {
```

to:

```
if (!isset($_COOKIE['verified'])) {
```

or:

```
if($_SESSION['verified'] != "yes"){
```

Comment: I tried both variations and got the same result. Have you tried the entire script yourself? I noted that the Visited in the first script is verified in the second, so that was a logical suggestion. But it still redirects to that video.

Comment: If it helps anybody trying to help me, my question is: "Which part of the code needs to be changed in order to redirect correctly?" I've posted all the code because I don't know what hinges upon what. I was hoping the "1 Answer" would work, but it made no difference. Thank you, Relentless, for the suggestion, though.

Comment: what about this: if(isset($_POST['YES']))  i dont see an input field with a name of "YES"

Comment: also some browsers like chrome need additional information in the cookie: setcookie("name", $val, $expire, $path, $domain, $secure, $httponly);

Comment: also when you do this:  $_COOKIE['Visited'] = 1; it wont write to the cookie, you have to use the setcookie() function. so try these three fixes

Comment: Relentless, I think you are on to something. You may have provided the answer, but I'm having to plod through this to understand. I agree that "Yes" in the form doesn't exist. The code was from a "Yes/No" answer form. Now it's an age input by typing in the 2 digit month, 2 digit day, and 4 digit year.

Comment: The code to calculate the month, day and year - mktime - is where the "Yes" is now. Is that correct, or should the "Yes" be something else?

Comment: i rewrote the code, and made a sample for you to take apart, i added it as another answer, let me know what you think. i can help you understand it if you need. i found out that you cant name a cookie visited for some reason, that was your problem the whole time, along with a couple of other things.

Answer (score 0):

K I found the problem, it seems that $_COOKIE["Visited"] cannot be used, it must be like a system standard for something, so you have to change it to something else: visitedherebefore. here is how I got it to work:

```
<?php

@session_start();
$showform = false;

    //created my own date function
function age($dob){ 
    $date1 = new DateTime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime($dob)));
    $date2 = new DateTime(date("Y-m-d"));
    $interval = $date1->diff($date2);
    return $interval->y;
}

    //if a form is submitted do the following
if(array_key_exists("submit", $_POST)){
    $m = $_POST["month"];
    $d = $_POST["day"];
    $y = $_POST["year"];

    $age = age($y."-".$m."-".$d);
    //check age here
    if($age > 17){
                    //set cookie here and redirect here if you want
        setcookie('visitedherebefore', 'Cookies seems legit', time() + 3600);
        die("Old enough... nuff said...");
    }else{
                    //redirect here as well
        die("Too Young Sorry! you will now be redirected");
    }
}

    //check if user has been here before, redirect here as well if you want
if (isset($_COOKIE['visitedherebefore'])) {
  print "welcome back!";
  die();
}
```

?>

```
<form action="index.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" tabindex="1" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" onkeyup="jumpField(this,this.value)" id="month" name="month" maxlength="2" size="2" required="required" value="MM" onfocus="value=''" />
    <input type="text" tabindex="2" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" onkeyup="jumpField(this,this.value)" id="day" name="day" maxlength="2" size="2" required="required" value="DD" onfocus="value=''"  />
    <input type="text" tabindex="3" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" onkeyup="jumpField(this,this.value)" id="year" name="year" maxlength="4" size="4" required="required" value="YYYY" onfocus="value=''" />
    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="Enter Superior Vaping" id="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: I may be missing something, but I couldn't get that to work for me.

Comment: if you copy and paste this into its own index.php page, you will see how it works

Comment: or try changing your cookie name

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make the following work, to my surprise. I don't think I was any better at coding, only more diligent and unwilling to give up.
Here is my resolve:
Remember, I'm working on a Joomla! platform, so the index.php is the foundation page for every page in the site. Therefore, to begin the verification no matter what page the visitor uses for entry, the initial code has to go into the templates/?template-name?/index.php

```
<?php   
    if(!isset($_COOKIE['legal'])) {         
    header("Location: verifyage.php");   
    }

    if($_COOKIE['legal'] == "no")
                    {
                    header("Location: http://www.google.com/");  
                    }
```

?>

Then, in the verifyage.php I used the following:

```
<?php
    /*if the cookie already exists from a previous remember me button click then skip this page*/                   
    error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE); //I don't know if that's right, but it works to keep the 1 error off the page - not by fixing, but hiding the error of legal not defined

    if($_COOKIE['legal'] == "yes")
                    {
                    header("Location: index.php");   
                    }                       

    if (isset($_POST['checkage'])) 
    {
    $day = '';
    $month = '';
    $year = '';
    $minage = '18';


    if(isset($_POST['day']))
            {
            $day = $_POST['day'];
            }

    if(isset($_POST['month']))
            {
            $month = $_POST['month'];
            }

    if(isset($_POST['year']))
            {
            $year = $_POST['year'];
            }



    $birthstamp = mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, $day, $year);
    $diff = time() - $birthstamp;
    $age_years = floor($diff / 31556926);

    if($age_years >= $minage) 
            {
            if($rembox=="yes")
                    {
                    setcookie('legal', 'yes', time() + 31556926);
                    }
                    else{
                    setcookie('legal', 'yes', 0);

                    }
                    $url = 'index.php';
            } 
    else 
            {
            setcookie('legal', 'no', 0);
            $url = 'http://www.google.com/';
            }

    header('Location: '.$url.'');
    }
```

?>

In the same page I added the following HTML which provides the lightbox effect and creates the fields for input:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Age Verification</title>
<script language=Javascript>
  <!--
  function isNumberKey(evt)
  {
     var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
     if (charCode != 46 && charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
        return false;

     return true;
  }
  //-->
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function jumpField(elmnt,content)
{
if (content.length==elmnt.maxLength)
{
next=elmnt.tabIndex
if (next<document.forms[0].elements.length)
    {
    document.forms[0].elements[next].focus()
    }
    }
}
</script>
<script src="http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.5/full/jquery.tools.min.js"></script> 
<script src="js/fade.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="js/ageverify.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body id="body" OnLoad="document.ageVerifyForm.month.focus();">
<img src="images/logoVerify.png" alt="Superior Vaping" id="logoVerify" /><br />
<p id="welcome">Welcome! Please enter your date of birth.</p>
<form id="ageVerifyForm" name="ageVerifyForm" action="" method="POST" onsubmit="return formCheck(this);">
<input type="text" tabindex="1" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" onkeyup="jumpField(this,this.value)" id="month" name="month" maxlength="2" size="2" required="required" value="MM" onfocus="value=''" />
<input type="text" tabindex="2" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" onkeyup="jumpField(this,this.value)" id="day" name="day" maxlength="2" size="2" required="required" value="DD" onfocus="value=''"  />
<input type="text" tabindex="3" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" onkeyup="jumpField(this,this.value)" id="year" name="year" maxlength="4" size="4" required="required" value="YYYY" onfocus="value=''" />
<br />
<input type="submit" value="Verify Your Entry" id="submit" name="checkage" />
</form>
<script language="JavaScript">
<!--
function formCheck(formobj){
// Enter name of mandatory fields
var fieldRequired = Array("month", "day", "year");
// Enter field description to appear in the dialog box
var fieldDescription = Array("month", "day", "year");
// dialog message
var alertMsg = "Please complete the following fields:\n";

var l_Msg = alertMsg.length;

for (var i = 0; i < fieldRequired.length; i++){
    var obj = formobj.elements[fieldRequired[i]];
    if (obj){
        switch(obj.type){
        case "select-one":
            if (obj.selectedIndex == -1 || obj.options[obj.selectedIndex].text == ""){
                alertMsg += " - " + fieldDescription[i] + "\n";
            }
            break;
        case "select-multiple":
            if (obj.selectedIndex == -1){
                alertMsg += " - " + fieldDescription[i] + "\n";
            }
            break;
        case "text":
        case "textarea":
            if (obj.value == "" || obj.value == null){
                alertMsg += " - " + fieldDescription[i] + "\n";
            }
            break;
        default:
        }
        if (obj.type == undefined){
            var blnchecked = false;
            for (var j = 0; j < obj.length; j++){
                if (obj[j].checked){
                    blnchecked = true;
                }
            }

        }
      }
    }

if (alertMsg.length == l_Msg){
    return true;
    }else{
    document.getElementById("error").innerHTML="All Fields Must be Filled out";
    return false;
    }
}
// -->
</script>
<p id="error"></p><br />
</body>
</html>
```

As I posted the code here I could see there 'may' be some code or lines that are unnecessary. But I can say that it worked so well that I've already implemented the code into the live site.
If anybody thinks there are some "don't to that" or "I wouldn't...", feel free to chime in because I'm not claiming to be any expert. I'm only posting a resolve to what I sought - a month ago. I'm pretty sure that the Onload can be removed.
I appreciate all the help that Relentless provided. I hope that posting this will be of value to others. If you have questions or would like to tell me I've done something that's just unforgivable, I'm willing to field all information. Thanks.